# How to list gradle modules on command line?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a project directory that looks like:

```
MyProject
├── *app*
├── build
├── build.gradle
├── gradle
├── gradle.properties
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
├── keystore.properties
├── local.properties
├── *module2*
├── *module3*
└── settings.gradle
```

where the modules have been highlighted.

I know I can build a task of a particular module / subproject by doing:

```
./gradlew module:assemble
```

and I can get all tasks with:

```
./gradlew tasks
```

But how can I get the names of the modules themselves (i.e. app, module2, module3)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`projects` is the task you're looking for. e.g.:

```
> ./gradlew -q projects

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project 'my-project-name'
------------------------------------------------------------

Root project 'my-project-name'
+--- Project ':apps'
|    \--- Project ':apps:api'
\--- Project ':libs'
     +--- Project ':libs:common'
     +--- Project ':libs:http-client'
     +--- Project ':libs:http-server'
     \--- Project ':libs:test-common'

To see a list of the tasks of a project, run gradlew <project-path>:tasks
For example, try running gradlew :apps:tasks
```

Answer (score 8):

This is not an optimal solution, but before we get a proper one may be useful. Running this command

```
./gradlew tasks --all
```

You will get all tasks for all modules, so to get all modules that can be assembled, you can use this oneliner:

```
./gradlew tasks --all | grep ":assemble" | cut -d: -f1 | sort -u
```

Comment: Could you explain what all the commands and parameters do exactly?